# mapValues function in DStream class Not Found

Tags: spark-streaming, dstream

I want to do some modifications on the StreamingKMeans algorithm provided in Spark Streaming, so I created a project containing the necessary files but unfortunately I can not find the mapValues function in the DStream class !

```
def predictOnValues[K: ClassTag](data: DStream[(K, Vector)]): DStream[(K, Int)] = {
  assertInitialized()
  data.mapValues(model.predict) //ERROR here !!!
}
```

Could someone tell me where can I find the mapValues function ?! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.toPairDStreamFunctions

should fix it.